# Is there a way to create Nativescript mobile applications using VIsual Studio (not VS Code)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I was searching for this and couldn't find anything regarding this topic .
The only similar thing was using the AppBuilder VS plugin which must be bought(or try it for 30 days).

Also working with angular2-nativescript would be a bonus .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NativeScript is completely IDE agnostic and you can use whatever IDE (or plain text editor) you want. (Me personally, I'm running JetBrain's WebStorm).

[Getting Started](http://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-1) will guide you though all steps of how to build your app.